# how to make a Google callable function only accessible on certain client app?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use Callable Function from Google Cloud Function like this

```
export const sendNotification = functions
.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 })
.region("asia-southeast2")
.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

});
```

so I make a separate Android app just to send custom FCM notification, so I want to prevent this `sendNotification` callable function to be used in my main app (iOS and Android).

is there any native way from firebase or google to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to not be possible, but this past May Firebase release App Check, which does precisely what you're looking.

With App Check, all requests coming from your iOS, Android, and web apps are verified and signed, and you can then enforce that only requests with such a verification are accepted in your
callable Cloud Functions.

For full documentation and examples, see the Firebase documentation on [enabling App Check enforcement for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions).